# How to get the return value outside the outer method

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, type-conversion, data-conversion

I'm new to angular and I'm confuse with a issue to get a return value of it. i have implement a function inside another.

```
private validateKeyterm(): boolean {
        const val = this.form.value.term;      
        if (this.selectedTermType == 'keywords') {
            // filter out data
            this.keywordTemp.filter(function (d) {
              if((d.term.toString().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val) == true){
                    console.log("keytemp: true");
                    return true;
                }
             
            }) ;
        } else {
            this.profanityTemp.filter(function (d) {
                if((d.term.toString().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val) == true){
                    console.log("profanity: true");
                    console.log("true");
                    return true;
                }
                else{ return null;}

            });
        }
        console.log("false");
        return false;
    }
```

But I'm getting the return value as "fail" always in this function execution. can anyone could find me a solution to get the "true" case out of the "validateKeyterm" function.

Comment: Have you tried to check if these variables have a value? Try to console.log all of them, only by precaution.

Comment: Yes. these variables have boolean value. I can go inside the if condition and console.log("keytemp: true") and console.log("profanity: true"). So it must be return "true". But it is only within that scope. Then the outer function return "false" in every occasion.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to check the values that you are using in this function, but based in your code, I suggest you to use arrow functions in filter function, like this:

```
  private validateKeyterm(): boolean {
    const val = this.form.value.term;      
    if (this.selectedTermType == 'keywords') {
        // filter out data
        return !!(this.keywordTemp.filter(d => {
          if((d.term.toString().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val) == true){
                console.log("keytemp: true");
                return true;
            }
         
        }));
    } else {
        return (this.profanityTemp.filter( d => {
            if((d.term.toString().indexOf(val) !== -1 || !val) == true){
                console.log("profanity: true");
                console.log("true");
                return true;
            }
            else{ return null;}

        }));
    }
    console.log("false");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I can still get "false" as the return value in validateKeyterm() even though i can console.log("keytemp: true") and console.log("profanity: true"). What i actually need is to return the true value in the condition checked from the validateKeyterm function

Comment: the answer has been edited, try again in this new suggestion

Comment: i'm getting a compilation error from the second condition check, that convert the return type to any. By the way i tried to add this return "return !!" for the first condition as well. But from that i'm getting "true" as the return even the two conditions get fail(can not console.log("profanity: true")).

Comment: I got this resolved by using a number variable instead of a boolean. number will be updated in the particular scope. thanks for the help